# Best Output for table data (object oriented programming, numpy, drill down results, GUI)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pygtk

Trying to take my calculations in python, and put them into an interactive table. I assume object oriented programming key for this behind the scene, using Pandas and Numpy.
So how do I create something lets with a grid of results with people and taxes paid as rows and columns.  If I were to click one of the values in the table, I would get an option to see the underlying values/variables used to calculate that particular field.  This sounds like a GUI, perhaps using GT or Tkinter, but wanted to see what people had for thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

These are usually BI Analyst or Data analyst tools. Tableau, Spotfire, Jump, etc, are purpose built for analyzing and plotting tabular data exactly as you're describing. [Here's an answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21028/best-free-alternative-to-tableau) showing a few free alternatives to these analyst tools.

But to answer your question, yes this would definitely be a GUI. The GUI framework that you use (Tkinter, GT, QT, or maybe even matplotlib) is up to your preference since they're all capable of doing this (some with more effort). [PandasTable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable) and [PreDator](https://scfbm.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1751-0473-9-21) could be used as reference.